# Help me interpret this audio jack schematic

Tags: switches, audio, connector, schematics, headphones

I'm having trouble interpreting the following schematic:

[image: Adam Tech ASJ-99H-R-HT-T/R schematic]

From this drawing: [Adam Tech ASJ-99H-R-HT-T/R drawing](http://www.adam-tech.com/downloader.php?p=ASJ-99H-X-HT-TR.pdf)

I want to know:

- Are 5 and 6 normally open (open when there's no plug inserted), or normally closed?
- Are 2 and 5 electrically isolated from one another or shorted together?

I don't have a sample on hand; the schematic should contain enough information to answer these questions.

If anyone can link to a resource that can explain the schematic symbols, that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The schematic is a bit confusing, or this is a multi-purpose connector. It is being called a stereo jack, yet pin call-outs are (1)=GND, (3)= TIP, (2)=RING, as if it was a telephone switch-board jack from many decades ago.

In the days of mechanical switchboards this connect/disconnect feature allowed a used jack to light a small lamp. Each jack had its own telephone line to a house. In my Army days in the 1970's I had to wire up a switchboard upon arriving at a location. Each platoon had its own phone and ringer handle.

As a stereo jack pin 1 = GND or common return, 2 = Right channel and 3 = Left channel. If present, pins 4, 5, and 6  are for routing the sound to speakers, such that plugging in the headphones disconnects the speakers.

In todays stereo's speakers *should* be disconnected if headphones are plugged in. Normally headphones have series resistors of a few hundred ohms to prevent blowing out the headphones, which have nowhere near the power rating of speakers. To make the headphones sound "loud" the volume setting might be too high for speakers, or too loud for the neighbors, so it is just as well if speakers are cut off when the headphones are being used.

Comment: Thanks for the hint and the story. For my application, I want to use the headphone jack as a replacement for an on-off toggle switch, or latching switch circuit. It's a kind of battery-powered telegraph key for practising sending Morse code; it should really only be on when something's plugged in.

Is there any chance you could point me to a drawing for an old switchboard-type jack for comparison?

Comment: Telephone lines were dual wires with Earth as a common ground, a third wire of sorts. TIP and RING were the pair of wires that went to your house. -48 volts was (and still is) normal power, and the phone had to be Earth grounded so it would work.

Comment: That's awesome. I was wondering why T and R were used to label the pins.

Comment: @Sparky256 ring voltage was always AC and has nothing to do with the telephone jack terminal names.  tip and ring are just physical descriptions. 1 is called sleeve but often used for GND.

Comment: @Jansen Thanks for the correction. This stuff is from many decades ago.

Answer (score 1):

They've provided a very poor drawing.

- 3 and 4 obviously disconnect when the jack is inserted.
- I suspect that 5 and 6 do as well but that contact is isolated from 2. That way it can be configured to work the same way as the tip contact by permanently connecting 2 to 5. When the jack is inserted 2 will be disconnected from 6.
- Alternatively you could leave 5 and 6 isolated and, for example, connect them to a device's MCU or audio controller. This provides a clean means of detecting the insertion of the jack.